# XCode - multiple instances of custom class

Tags: objective-c, class, instances

New to XCode, coming from a VB.net background so may be missing something basic.

Have created a .h and .m file for a basic class. Code listed below.

```
//
//  tttMove.h
//  TicTocToe
//
//  Created by Matthew Baker on 12/09/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Matthew Baker. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface tttMove : NSObject

-(id)init;
-(id)initWithPos :(int)newAcross :(int)newDown ;

-(void)setAcross:(int)newAcross;
-(void)setDown:(int)newDown;
-(void)set:(int)newAcross :(int)newDown;

-(int)across;
-(int)down;

-(void)showResults;

@end


//
//  tttMove.m
//  TicTocToe
//
//  Created by Matthew Baker on 12/09/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Matthew Baker. All rights reserved.
//

#import "tttMove.h"

@implementation tttMove

int _across;
int _down;

-(id) init {
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        _across = 0;
        _down = 0;
    }
    return self;
}
-(id)initWithPos :(int)newAcross :(int)newDown {
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        _across = newAcross;
        _down = newDown;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)showResults {
    NSLog(@"move position %i,%i",_across,_down);
}

-(void)setAcross:(int)newAcross {
    _across = newAcross;
}
-(void)setDown:(int)newDown {
    _down = newDown;
}
-(void)set:(int)newAcross :(int)newDown {
    _across = newAcross;
    _down = newDown;
}
-(int)across {
    return _across;
}
-(int)down {
    return _down;
}
@end
```

Problem I'm having is that I when I create multiple instances of the same class, they always share common values. Cannot update one without the other...

```
-(void) test {

    tttMove *move1 = [[tttMove alloc] initWithPos:1 :1];
    [move1 showResults];

    tttMove *move2 = [[tttMove alloc] initWithPos:2 :2];
    [move2 showResults];

    [move1 showResults];

}
```

The output I get is:

```
2013-09-15 23:01:35.004 TicTocToe[19925:c07] move position 1,1
2013-09-15 23:01:35.006 TicTocToe[19925:c07] move position 2,2
2013-09-15 23:01:35.006 TicTocToe[19925:c07] move position 2,2
```

Which means although I'm calling the alloc init, I'm not getting a new instance.

I'm assuming I've missed something basic, but googling hasn't helped. Probably not even searching for the right thing.

Thanks in advance for the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the @property instead of `int _across`; and `int _down`;.
and remove the sets method, because if you use the @property, the initializer are automatically provided by Xcode.

so try :

```
@property (nonatomic) int across;

@property (nonatomic) int down;
```

and remove `int _across`; and `int _down`.
If you need more information about properties, and how does they work:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Max_Power89.  His answer is correct. Finished code now looks like :

.h File

```
//
//  tttMove.h
//  TicTocToe
//
//  Created by Matthew Baker on 12/09/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Matthew Baker. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface tttMove : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int across;
@property (nonatomic) int down;

-(id)init;
-(id)initWithPos :(int)newAcross :(int)newDown ;

-(void)set:(int)newAcross :(int)newDown;
-(void)showResults;

@end
```

.m File

```
//
//  tttMove.m
//  TicTocToe
//
//  Created by Matthew Baker on 12/09/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Matthew Baker. All rights reserved.
//

#import "tttMove.h"

@implementation tttMove

@synthesize across;
@synthesize down;

-(id) init {
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        [self setAcross:0];
        [self setDown:0];
    }
    return self;
}
-(id)initWithPos :(int)newAcross :(int)newDown {
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        [self setAcross:newAcross];
        [self setDown:newDown];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)showResults {

    NSLog(@"move position %i,%i",[self across],[self down]);
}

-(void)set:(int)newAcross :(int)newDown {
    [self setAcross:newAcross];
    [self setDown:newDown];
}

@end
```

Thanks again for your help.